# Reversing array fetch from restkit causes bad access

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to show data stored in an array initialized from a restkit fetch on a tableView in reverse order, then delete a selected item.

The code as originally set up works fine (non-reversed), with the setup like this:

```
arrScans = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: [context executeFetchRequest:myScans error:&error]];
```

But when I try to access the (sorted) array, I get a bad access .

Here's the code the loads the sorted data:

```
arrScansOrig = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: [context executeFetchRequest:myScans error:&error]];
arrScans = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[arrScansOrig count]];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [arrScansOrig reverseObjectEnumerator];
for (id element in enumerator) {
    [arrScans addObject:element];
}

NSLog(@"arrScans: %@",arrScans);
```

Then, when I attempt to delete the item (shift to edit view, select, click "delete" button", arrScans accesses a bad memory location.

```
-(void)btnDelete
{
        NSLog(@"arrScans: %@",arrScans);
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I should've thought about it earlier, but I wasn't trying to figure out what was in the actual array entries - the database rows, or objects representing them. While I still didn't work out exactly how they looked, I did try a "deep" copy - and it worked.

Here's the code:

// need to show in reverse order

```
arrScansOrig = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: [context executeFetchRequest:myScans error:&error]];

NSArray *myArray = [[arrScansOrig reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [myArray mutableCopy];

arrScans = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: myMutableArray];
```